# Make Ecto schema field name different than source table column name (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm currently working on a Phoenix project where I'm unsatisfied with the way I'm calling fields in the templates.

The schema is currently

```
defmodule MyApp.Car do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  schema "car" do
    field :columnName, :string
  end
end
```

`car = Repo.get!(Car, id)`

I'd like to be able to call the result with
`car.column_name`
rather than
`car.columnName`

Migrating the database isn't currently an option due to a number of applications using the database.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible at this time.

Comment: I guess you could create a view and use it in your schema, thats one way to go about it but I believe it will work only with selects.

Answer (score 11):

There is a [`source` option for `field`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3).

> :source - Defines the name that is to be used in database for this
>   field.

```
defmodule MyApp.Car do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  schema "car" do
    field :column_name, :string, source: :columnName
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be done Ecto's [field source mapper](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-schema-attributes).

```
defmodule MyApp.Car do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @field_source_mapper fn
    :column_name -> :columnName
    x -> x
  end

  schema "car" do
    field :column_name, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Ecto schema to use snake_case for column names that reference camelCase columns, you will need to create a view. If your view is just used to rename columns, it will be "[updatable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html)" in Postgres/MySql/Microsoft SQL Server. This means that `INSERT`'s `UPDATE`'s and `DELETE`'s into the view will write to the actual table the view references.

For example, if you car table definition looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE car(
   id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   modelName      VARCHAR(255),
   makeName       VARCHAR(255),
   manufacturerId INT REFERENCES manufacturer(id)
);
```

you can create a migration that creates a view selecting from each column with a snake_case alias name:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CarView do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    execute """
      CREATE VIEW my_app_car
      AS
      SELECT
          id AS id,
          modelName AS model_name,
          makeName AS make_name,
          manufacturerId AS manufacturer_id
      FROM car; 
    """
  end

  def down do
    execute "DROP VIEW my_app_car;"
  end
end
```

and your Ecto Schema would just need to use your view as its source ("my_app_car" instead of "car"):

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Car do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  schema "my_app_car" do
    field :model_name, :string
    field :make_name, :string
    belongs_to :manufacturer, MyApp.Manufacturer
  end
end
```

You can then use your `MyApp.Car` Ecto schema as if its source were the original "car" table, but with the modified column names.

If you're using a database that supports [schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-schemas.html), (e.g. Postgres, SQL Server) you can create a separate schema for your views, instead of naming all of your ecto views "my_app_[TABLE NAME]".